# How to calucate recall at k when the number of relevant document is large?

Tags: information-retrieval

In information retrieval, how to calculate r@k when the number of the relevant document is large? The formular is:

$
\text{Recall@K} = \frac{\text{True positive}}{\text{relevant document}}
$

If relevant document is too large, R@K will be very small regardless of k. How can I handle it?